# How style the show entries and increase the fontsize of the font from Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am working with an `HTML` file. Since my data is mainly tabular data. I leveraged on the beautiful styling `Datatables` offers. However, I would like to change the `colour, border colour` and increase the select icon beside the `show entries` and `increase the text`. For your convenience *Einträge anzeigen* is *show entry* just basically the *de version*.

Here is how it looks like right now:

[image]

And here is my corresponding javascript file incase you need to make reference:

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");


           $('table thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( 'table thead' );
           $('thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
               if(i > 4){
                   $(this).hide()
               }
           })

            $('table').DataTable( {

                fixedHeader: true,

                language: {
                    processing:     "Bitte warten ..",
                    search:         "Suchen",
                    lengthMenu:    "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",              
                    info:           "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
                    infoEmpty:      "Keine Daten vorhanden",
                    infoFiltered:   "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
                    infoPostFix:    "",
                    loadingRecords: "Wird geladen ..",
                    zeroRecords:    "Keine Einträge vorhanden",
                    paginate: {
                        first:      "Erste",
                        previous:   "Zurück",
                        next:       "Nächste",
                        last:       "Letzte"}
                    },

                   initComplete: function () {

                       this.api().columns().every( function () {

                           var column = this;

                           console.log(column.index())
                           var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                               .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                               .on( 'change', function () {
                                   var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                       $(this).val()
                                   );

                                   column
                                       .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                       .draw();
                               } );

                           column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                               select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                           } );
                       } );
                   }
               } );

       } );

</script>
```

Comment: Right click in your browser, click "inspect", see what classes DT are using for those elements and create custom CSS accordingly.  Without overestimating there are +50 answers on that particular issue on SO.

Comment: How can I show you what it shows? Let me update the question. Its quite confusing

Comment: Here is a sample: `.dataTables_length { color: red; } .dataTables_length select { border:1px solid lime; }` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add CSS to make the element container for the `select` bigger

```
.dataTables_length, .dataTables_length select{ font-size: 2em;}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to add a space between the select box and the actual table?

Comment: it is just CSS to add some margin-bottom i.e. `.dataTables_length {margin-bottom: 1em;}` or whatever space you need (or add margin-top to table)